# Check old urls for backlinks - same domain new design and urls

Tags: seo, search-engines, 301-redirect, backlinks, anchor

I have a client who recently did a re-design on his website. The designer did not put any effort in keeping the same URL or do any redirects. I've made a list of the old URLs, what I want to do now is check if these URLs have links that pass any juice.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to see if the old URLs that are linking to 404 carry any backlinks and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) is probably your easiest bet here. In the 'Crawl Errors' section it will list 404s it found crawling your site, along with the pages that link to them. It may not be a completely exhaustive list but it will have the majority of them.

Comment: thanks alot tim, those should be enough, found around 1500 404s with approximately 10 000 backlinks so it should do the trick :) thank you

Comment: domain is around 8 years old and all links are natural.

Comment: @user27594 its worth noting Google only displays a chunk of backlinks and not all.

Comment: @bybe anyway of finding the rest of them then?